# Visual Studio 2017 linux project from existing source

Tags: visual-studio-2017, ubuntu-18.04, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I have configured successfully the Visual Studio 2017 enviroment for Ubuntu 18 (via WSL) and I can compile/execute simple projects. But I have a problem with the following project.

My C++ code is located in the WSL enviroment in the user home which I can explore throught the AppData folder in Windows. The project consists of the following files:

```
src-> main.cpp
   -> libs -> A-> A.h, A.cpp
           -> B-> B.h, B.cpp
       ...
```

On visual studio, I have only two options. Either I create a new empty linux project but I cannot add all the files to project keeping the same folder structure, or creating a project from existing source but there is no option to create a linux project. I would create a linux project from source files located in the WSL installation keeping the same file structure. Adding the source files to the project get them flattened to the root and the prject can be compiled correctly. I don't want to create folders manually since they are a lot.
How can I solve?

Comment: Does that project contain Linux code or Windows code?

Comment: It contains Linux code.